# SolrPhpClient Delete function

Tags: php, indexing, solr

I am having some trouble deleting documents from Solr index. I use following code:

```
    try{
        $solr->deleteById('1');
        $solr->commit();
        $solr->optimize();
    }catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

This code sometimes succeeds, but most of the time the following exception message is returned: **"0" Status: Communication Error**

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to get Solr log data, but I have noticed some odd thing - I started getting exceptions even when I am adding data. And even though I am getting exceptions changes still take place once I restart Tomcat server, and script, when run first time after restart, is successfully executed...

Comment: You need to check the log to see the reason for the error. See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have quickly dropped my own Solr client class using code written by Brian Lucas. It is a bit raw but straightforward and seems to solve the problem. [Source code](http://snipt.org/QlH)